# Breusch Pagan R test which function is correct

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, breusch-pagan

So I have a model:
$log(y)= \beta_0 + \beta_1dog +\beta_2cat$.

I want to test for heteroskedasticity using a Breusch-Pagan test and the variables cat and dog.

Should by formula be
`bptest(log(data$y)~ data$dog + data$cat)`
or

`bptest(data$y ~ data$dog + data$cat)`?

Comment: You have your model before testing for heteroscedasticity, i.e., you did not take the log of the outcome after `bptest`. Right?

Comment: It should be the same formula as the formula for the linear model you are interested in